# Why isn't my function returning?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

Below is a function that starts an external process, matches a regular expression against the process' standard output, and returns the contents of the match.

```
func (c *Colony) startCircuit(peer *string) (string, error) {
    var (
        err        error
        cmd        *exec.Cmd
        anchorChan chan string
    )

    // ... (omitted for readability)

    // get the anchor from standard output
    go func() {
        defer out.Close()

        anchorChan = make(chan string)
        for scanner := bufio.NewScanner(out); scanner.Scan(); {
            line := scanner.Text()
            if anchor := reRootAnchor.FindString(line); anchor != "" {
                log.Println("Started circuit server with anchor:", anchor)
                anchorChan <- anchor
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    anchor := <-anchorChan
    return anchor, err
}
```

When running the function, I obtain the following output, which shows that a match is indeed found and (presumably) pushed into `anchorChan`:

```
2016/05/22 14:04:36 Started circuit server with anchor: circuit://[::]:36195/20666/Q431cc5fe613aa04b
```

However, `startCircuit`'s caller seems to hang.  Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
rootAnchor, err := c.startCircuit(peer)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
log.Fatal(rootAnchor) // DEBUG
```

Why is `startCircuit` hanging indefinitely instead of returning?

Comment: Just curious, why `defer` is in the goroutine? (I'm assuming you open the file in the `starCircuit` function)

Comment: Also, can you provide a MWE? I'm a bit curious to try myself :)

Comment: @T.Claverie You removed your answer but your suggestion to move the `make` call outside of the goroutine seems to have fixed the issue.  Feel free to resubmit your answer!

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion. It appears that `anchor := <-anchorChan` is trying to receive on an uninitialized channel since `make` is called from within the go routine.

Comment: @blz Then I am glad it helped. I deleted it because the comment made me doubt my solution would work on your case, and I didn't want to mislead you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in fact quite simple. Hint: the following code ends in a **deadlock**.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var c chan string

    go func() {
        c = make(chan string)
        c <- "42"
    }()

    str := <-c
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

From there, the problem is trivial. Your channel is not initialized when you start the goroutine. There is a race with the two goroutines, and apparently go cannot decide which should have the priority.

So, your answer is: call `make(chan ...)` before the goroutine starts, it should solve your problem. There is a perfect example of this in [effective go.](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels)

Comment: I don't think this is _quite_ right -- the assignment to `c` inside the goroutine races with the `str := <-c` statement outside the goroutine. So the assignment does affect the channel in the main function, and the code isn't guaranteed to deadlock, but it's definitely broken because it contains a race. The race detector will catch this.

Comment: Thanks for showing me my wrongs, I was mistaken about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dave Cheney has a good related blog post: http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms

Most relevant points:

1. A send to a nil channel blocks forever
2. A receive from a nil channel blocks forever

Since uninitialized channel is nil, and thus any read and write to it will result in deadlock. In example, in T. Claverie's answer, there is a race: If `c = make(chan string)`, (and `c <- "42"`, I believe that `str := <-c` has to wait at this point) happen first, then receive happens from initialized, non-empty channel and everything is runs fine:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    var c chan string

    go func() {
        c = make(chan string)
        c <- "42"
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    str := <-c
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oLs1-Kh3P3)

You can run the above example to convince yourself. (This is not good practice or even guaranteed to work every time.)

However, if `str := <-c` happens first, then you are receiving from an `nil` channel, which results in a deadlock.